# Is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by several random variables equal to the preimage of the $\sigma$-algebra on the product space?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $\Omega \neq \emptyset$ be a nonempty set and let $(\Omega_1, \mathcal{A}_1),...,(\Omega_n, \mathcal{A}_n)$ be a finite number of measurable spaces. Furthermore, let $X_i :  \Omega \rightarrow \Omega_i$ be maps and $X : \Omega \rightarrow \Omega_1 \ \times ... \times \ \Omega_n $ defined as $X(w) := (X_1(w),...,X_n(w))$.

We denote the sigma-operator with $\sigma$, so that for maps to measurable spaces $X_1,...,X_n$, $\sigma(X_1,...,X_n)$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra so that all $X_i$ are measurable. I have the suspicion that the following equality holds:

$$ \sigma(X_1,...,X_n) = X^{-1}(\mathcal{A}_1 \ \otimes...\otimes \ \mathcal{A}_n) $$

Is this always the case?

Kind regards and thanks for any help,

Joker

Comment: okay how do you define the preimage of a sigma algebra?

Comment: Sorry, I should have added this definition:

$X^{-1}(\mathcal{A}_1 \ \otimes...\otimes \ \mathcal{A}_n) := \{ X^{-1}(A) \ \vert \ A \in \mathcal{A}_1 \ \otimes...\otimes \ \mathcal{A}_n  \}$

It also helps to know, that the preimage of a $\sigma$-algebra under any map is again a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: As a start, the $\sigma$-algebra on the left is generated by subsets of $\Omega$ of the form $\cap_{k=1}^n\{\omega\in\Omega: X_k(\omega)\in A_k\}$, where $A_k\in\mathcal A_k$; such a generator can be expressed as $X^{-1}(A_1\times A_2\times\cdots\times A_n)$. This observation proves the containment $\subset$. A similar argument proves the other containment.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer! 

How do you know, that the left $\sigma$-algebra is generated by the sets you describe? Is this easy to see?

Moreover, would the statement also hold if I would consider an infinite sequence of random variables $(X_i)_{i=1}^{\infty}$ instead of just $X_1,...,X_n$ ?